# Django Admin list page: Custom Action Buttons (url) problem, what is wrong?

Tags: django, url, admin

i have followed this tutorial https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-admin-cookbook/en/latest/action_buttons.html

This is the relevant part of my code:

```
@admin.register(Partner)
class PartnerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_list_template = 'change_list.html'
    model = Partner
```

.
.
.

```
def get_urls(self):
    return super().get_urls() + [path('sync/', self.sync_partners, name='partners_sync_partners')]

@staff_member_required
def sync_partners(self, request):
    #TODO: Sync code should go here
    self.message_user(request, "Partners sync complete")
    return HttpResponseRedirect("../")
```

The url on template is referenced with `{% url 'admin:partners_sync_partners' %}` which is pointing to */admin/partners/partner/sync/* and i think it should be */admin/partners/sync/*

When i click the button, i am getting this error:

**Partner with ID "sync" doesn't exist. Perhaps it was deleted?**

I guess the problem is related with the url generated.
My code is inside my app 'partners' in *partners/admin.py* and my template is under partners/templates/change_list.html

PS: I'm using Django 2.1.1 and Python 3.6.5

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of custom user which i have created where i have to show all fields in django admin site for custom user .

so you can add that button in list display

```
list_display = ('email', 'phone','account_name','account_number','bank_name','bsb_number','account_summary')
```

now make that button a method and give url where you want to render it.

```
def account_summary(self,obj):
    ow_tags = True
    return format_html(
        '<a class="button" href="{}">Account</a>&nbsp;',reverse('all_accounts_view', args=[obj.pk]))
account_summary.allow_tags = True
```

dont forget to add
from django.urls import reverse